# Attaching info (id) to the vertices for a CGAL Poisson reconstruction

Tags: c++, cgal

I spent the day trying to achieve the following, with no luck. I have been able to attach an id to the vertices (`vertex()->info()`) for some triangulations, with the help of `std::pair`. But now I want to do so for a Poisson surface reconstruction, which uses a `Polyhedron_3` as a mesh, and I don't manage. Doing the Poisson surface reconstruction requires to use points with normals. So, for the points, I defined pairs constituted of a pair (point, normal) and an integer; my inputs are a matrix of points `pts` and a matrix of normals `normals` (these matrices come from R which runs the C++ code):

```
  const size_t npoints = pts.nrow();
  std::vector<IP3wn> points(npoints);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < npoints; i++) {
    points[i] = std::make_pair(
        std::make_pair(Point3(pts(i, 0), pts(i, 1), pts(i, 2)), i + 1),
        Vector3(normals(i, 0), normals(i, 1), normals(i, 2)));
  }
  Polyhedron mesh;
```

But I can't access to the field `info()` of the vertices:

```
for(Polyhedron::Facet_iterator fit = mesh.facets_begin();
    fit != mesh.facets_end(); fit++) {
  Polyhedron::Facet f = *fit;
  facets(i, 0) = f.halfedge()->vertex()->info();
```

The error message claims that there is no member `info`. Could you show me the right way please?

Comment: Use the following `typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel,CGAL::Polyhedron_items_with_id_3>  Polyhedron;` as Polyhedron type.

Comment: Thanks @sloriot, I gonna try. I've just tried with a tuple instead of my weird type, to put the id at the end, but that didn't work.

Comment: @sloriot The code has successfully compiled!!! One has to use `id()` and not `info()`. I gonna try on a point cloud now.

Comment: @sloriot There's something weird: all my `id()` are `-1`. Otherwise the vertices look correct.

Comment: I found [this discussion](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/issues/5362). I think I understand now: one has to assign the ids to the vertices of the computed mesh (`it->id() = counter`). Not to the vertices of the input mesh, as I thought.

Comment: Exactly, the algorithm converting the c2t3 into a Polyhedron does not set any id, so they are default initialized.